# Function not defined in XPinC

Tags: javascript, xpages

I'm using a short function to check XSP._isDirty, which works properly in the browser and in older versions of XPinC. When I put the code directly into a link on the custom control as the client side script, it runs, so it's not that _isDirty is no longer working.

In XPinC with 9.0.1, clicking links that call the function do not execute and complain the status bar that isClean is not defined.

My function is in my clientSideFunctions.js CSJS script library and loaded via the theme. Here's that loading:

```
<script target="xsp" src="/clientSideFunctions.js" clientSide="true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This works in 8.5.3 XPinC and in the browser.

```
function isClean() {
    try {
        if (XSP._isDirty()){
            if (confirm ("Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" + "\n" +
                    "This document may contain unsaved changes." + "\n" +
                    "Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page.")){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The function is invoked as the client side script for the links, so I can check whether the user has dirtied the page. When using these links, which execute javascript instead of just being links, enableModifiedFlag does not result in the nice little warning dialog.

```
<xp:link text="Excel reporting" escape="true" target="_self" id="link11" value="/util_ExcelReport.xsp">
    <xp:this.styleClass><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (compositeData.currentSubLink == "imp_ExcelExports") "selected"}]]></xp:this.styleClass>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[return isClean();]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:link>
```

So, if the code will execute and the script library is loaded in the theme, why does it keep throwing an error? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Is it really loaded ?

```
<script target="xsp" src="/clientSideFunctions.js" clientSide="true" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

that looks like you are trying to use an output script but you are using HTML tag SCRIPT

so the /clientSideFunctions.js will be tryign to load the library relative to the server.com/clientSideFunctions.js and not relative to the database.

Use this instead maybe ?

```
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:script src="/clientSideFunctions.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Comment: When you load it in the theme, you don't use the xp part of the tag. That said, I can't get it to load from there at all.